# Jquery DataTables Populate data from JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been trying to get this to work forever and really cant get it to work :(

I am building a MVC 5 application and the JSON string from the controller looks like this:

> [{"Action_Comment_ID":9,"Action_ID":36,"Comment":"Test
>   commrnt","Modified_by":null,"Modified_date":null,"Created_by":"bb1222b0-699e-4d6a-81fc-04ff68c8c5c6","Created_date":"/Date(1420066800000)/"}]

And I can see that by running alert(JSON.stringify(data));

The datatable is beeing populated on a click method and I am calling the controller with Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Case/ActionDetails/',
    data: JSON.stringify(Action),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {

        acTable.fnClearTable();

        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        acTable.fnAddData(data);

        console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

So how do i extract the data from the JSON string and add it to the DataTable. I want to extract each field by itself because I want to do things with each individual field.

The created date needs to be parsed with this method f.ex

```
created_date = new Date(parseInt(SOMEVARIABLE.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
```

And I want the fields to show different data depending on the record have been modified etc.

It can also be multiple records returned so if I add some more records it will look like this:

> [{"Action_Comment_ID":9,"Action_ID":36,"Comment":"Test comment
>   1","Modified_by":null,"Modified_date":null,"Created_by":"bb1222b0-699e-4d6a-81fc-04ff68c8c5c6","Created_date":"/Date(1420066800000)/"},{"Action_Comment_ID":11,"Action_ID":36,"Comment":"Test
>   comment
>   2","Modified_by":null,"Modified_date":null,"Created_by":"bb1222b0-699e-4d6a-81fc-04ff68c8c5c6","Created_date":"/Date(1388530800000)/"},{"Action_Comment_ID":12,"Action_ID":36,"Comment":"Test
>   comment
>   3","Modified_by":"bb1222b0-699e-4d6a-81fc-04ff68c8c5c6","Modified_date":"/Date(1405634400000)/","Created_by":"bb1222b0-699e-4d6a-81fc-04ff68c8c5c6","Created_date":"/Date(1405548000000)/"}]

Comment: JQuery Datatables can do it for you http://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: Jquery Datatables is what I am using.. I need a little bit more info on how do this. The table is already initialised because it have to be possible to open an empty table and add new records there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N62Ka/6/)

```
$.ajax({
url: '/Case/ActionDetails/', 
//data: JSON.stringify(Action), //I Didn't send any data
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
success: function () {
    $(result).each(function(){
        acTable.fnAddData([this.Comment]); 
    })
  }
});
```

`[this.Comment]` In this array you need to add your columns values, in same sequence as your columns placed.

Comment: Thats working perfect! Thanks alot. Is there an easy way to check if its empty? The data object looks like this when its nothing in it: {"Data":[]} Since I get an error if data is empty

Comment: @stibay The best idea, as for me, it's to return empty data and nonempty in very same format. empty {"Data":[]}/ nonempty {"Data":[column1:value1,...]} then you need to change `$(result).each` to `$(result.data).each`

Comment: Ok, thank you. From your suggestion I changed it up abit in the controller instead so it doesnt return anything when it's empty.